# Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException "double" input error

Tags: java, double, java.util.scanner

First of all, I've read the many threads about this error, but none solved my problem.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Programa1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        double strana_a, strana_b, strana_c;
        strana_a = s.nextDouble();
        //strana_b = s.nextDouble();
        //strana_c = s.nextDouble();

        System.out.println(strana_a);

        s.close();
    }

}
```

When I type 8.0 for example, it shows me this error, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Show us what you are entering exactly.

Comment: When I type "8" as input, it works fine. But if I type "8.5" for example, I get this error. I named my variables doubles because I need to work with such numbers.

Comment: Also cannot reproduce... Your exact code works fine for me with '8.5' as input.

Comment: Could you please try with '8,5' as input instead of '8.5'? I have no clue what is going wrong with your code,  so try this and tell us if the error still happens.

Comment: I think it's a problem with Locale...Does it work with "8,5"? (comma, not point)

Comment: It seems to be working with a comma. I didn't really think of that, because I've used C++ before and it was a dot, but in Eclipse I guess the default is comma. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you sure you didn't enter '8.o'

Comment: @user3755419 It's nothing to do with Eclipse. It's to do with your system locale. In France, for instance, a comma is used instead of a dot. If your locale is set to something along those lines, it'll insist on having a comma instead of a dot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As told in my previous comment (I'd like to convert it into an answer), it's a problem of the Locale (from the variables' names, it seems that you're Italian). Use comma instead as point (`8,5`, and not `8.5`), or initialize the Scanner using the proper Locale for point, like this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.US);
```